# Android Studio 2.2 start failed

Tags: android, android-studio

Just downloaded Android Studio Canary Build: 2.2 Preview 6, on trying to start I get:

```
Internal Error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:96)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:93)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:34)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I've googled and not been able to find any fixes.

I'm running Linux Mint Rebecca 17.1 32-bit.

Not sure what other information to provide. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you download a stable version first then upgrade the Previews?

Comment: @Eenvincible I was going to try that next, however I think I messed up the initial installation somehow, after a restart and reinstallation it seems to be working fine :)

Comment: Happy coding Njord!

Answer (score 1):

just install the jdk1.8.0_102 and set JAVA_PATH in your Environment Variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102

Answer (score 0):

I must have messed up installation somehow, after deleting `~/.AndroidStudioPreview1.2/` and `~/.AndroidStudioPreview2.2/` I redownloaded [the installation zip](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/canary/latest) and reinstalled. Now it seems to be working.